# send the new password - Asp.net - using gmail ( smtp.gmail.com )

Tags: asp.net, forgot-password

I've gone through all helps and all forums., but none of them have helped me. Here is my problem

1. Developing a site on localhost using  ASP.NET 3.5
2. I want to provide 'forgot password' functionality using `<asp:PasswordRecovery>`
3. Any real help is greatly appreciated. Please note that I want to send it by either changing web.config OR programatically.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell us what part you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article on MSDN explaining how to use the [PasswordRecovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335.aspx) control.

There is also a [thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1227533/2267618.aspx) specifically regarding using GMail with the control.

> I believe that the best way is to use the [SendingMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.sendingmail.aspx) event method and send your own email, thus setting the MailMessage object and the SmtpClient object within the method.  Then, set the [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.logincanceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property to true, so that the other email won't be sent.

I have not tried it myself though. If you want more specific help, show what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set smtp via web config:

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="testuser@domail.com">
                <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" port="25" userName="kaushal" password="testPassword"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```